# Is it possible to change the loss function dynamically during training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am working on a machine learning project and I am wondering whether it is possible to change the loss function while the network is training. I'm not sure how to do it exactly in code.

For example, start training with `cross entropy loss` and then halfway through training, switch to `0-1 loss`.

Comment: So, changing completely the problem halfway from a classification to a regression one, right?

Comment: @desertnaut Err - not quite. I've updated the example. Switching from cross-entropy loss to 0-1 loss.

Comment: Even changing halfway from classification from regression makes sense. Recently have started to learn on a discretised classification. After convergence changed the last layer and the problem So why not.
However, I wonder why don't you just do it?

Comment: @CAFEBABE I'm not sure how to do it practically in code. If you could provide a very simple example: that would be awesome

Comment: It would help if you would provide your initial code. In Keras it should be just a second call to compile. After maybe replacing the output layer

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your own algorithm. This is mostly possible with Tensorflow.

Comment: I get that. But I don't know how to practically do this in code with Tensorflow. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively recent paper that address this issue: [Learning to Teach with Dynamic Loss Functions](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7882-learning-to-teach-with-dynamic-loss-functions.pdf)